# How to hide parameter conditionally

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I was able to make inputs appear and dissappear with active choices plugin. But name of the parameter isn't hidden dynamically and I don't know how to achieve that.

Answer (score 3):

Updated 2023/1/1

Jenkins version: 2.384

Active Choices Plug-in: 2.6.4

[image]

In this version, `form-group` has become `jenkins-form-item`.

---

My Jenkins version is 2.272, I achieved that with Active Choices plugin too.

1. Add an `Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter` named `PARA_1`
2. Add an `Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter` named `PARA_2` that you want to hidden when `PARA_1` is checked
3. Set `Referenced parameters` with `PARA_1`

[image]

4. Set `Choice Type` with `Formatted HTML`
5. Write script

[image]

`PARA_1` script:

```
return "<input name='value' type='checkbox' checked='checked'>"
```

[image]

`PARA_2` script:

```
if (PARA_1) {
    return """
  <input name="value" id="PARA_2"  value="PARA_2">
  <img src="force/failed/load/image" style="display: none;" onerror='document.getElementById("PARA_2").closest(".jenkins-form-item").style.display=""'>
"""  
} else {
  return """
  <input name="value" id="PARA_2"  value="PARA_2">
  <img src="force/failed/load/image" style="display: none;" onerror='document.getElementById("PARA_2").closest(".jenkins-form-item").style.display="none"'>
""" 
}
```

<strike>The `form-group` is class name that find by Jenkins parameters HTML</strike>

6.Finally Build with Parameters
[image]

[image]

Comment: wasn't able to understand what .form-group actually is))
but for me it worked this way:
onerror='document.getElementById(Id).parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "none"

Comment: I think if you add a complete code or screenshot it will be more useful

Comment: According to the latest plug-in version, I modified the answer and inserted the picture.

Comment: Thanks, surprisingly it works pretty well, i even can reference the PARA_2 in the code of later choices and pass it as a build param to a python script

Answer (score 2):

### Introduction

I wanted to show parameters when checkbox was true and hide it when false. I achieved that with Active Choices plugin. Unfortunately if you give name to parameter, this name won't hide. So I came up with two solutions.

### First Solution

This solution has a little flaw. Because postion is set to "absolute" everything is ok as long as window size doesnt change. This code should be run as groovy script in "Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter" and reference PARAM_1. Parameter should return "Formatted HTML".

```
if(PARAM_1) {
def FullHTML = """
<label style="left: 19.9%; position: absolute;">input</label>
<input name='input_field' type='text'>
"""
return FullHTML
}
```

### Second Solution

This solution uses jquery to modify "setting-name" element. This code should be run as groovy script in "Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter" and reference PARAM_1. Parameter should return "Formatted Hidden HTML".

```
if(PARAM_1) {
def FullHTML = """
<input id='input_field' name='input_field' type='text'>
"""
return FullHTML
}
```

Add one more "Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter" which will containt this code. Again run as groovy script and return "Formatted Hidden HTML".

**EDIT**

I've modified this code to hide empty space when element isn't shown on the page. Because Jenkins puts it into table each row was taking space even if it was empty.

```
def FullHTML = """
<script>/*
 * arrive.js
 * v2.4.1
 * https://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive
 * MIT licensed
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2014-2017 Uzair Farooq
 */
var Arrive=function(e,t,n){"use strict";function r(e,t,n){l.addMethod(t,n,e.unbindEvent),l.addMethod(t,n,e.unbindEventWithSelectorOrCallback),l.addMethod(t,n,e.unbindEventWithSelectorAndCallback)}function i(e){e.arrive=f.bindEvent,r(f,e,"unbindArrive"),e.leave=d.bindEvent,r(d,e,"unbindLeave")}if(e.MutationObserver&&"undefined"!=typeof HTMLElement){var o=0,l=function(){var t=HTMLElement.prototype.matches||HTMLElement.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector||HTMLElement.prototype.mozMatchesSelector||HTMLElement.prototype.msMatchesSelector;return{matchesSelector:function(e,n){return e instanceof HTMLElement&&t.call(e,n)},addMethod:function(e,t,r){var i=e[t];e[t]=function(){return r.length==arguments.length?r.apply(this,arguments):"function"==typeof i?i.apply(this,arguments):n}},callCallbacks:function(e,t){t&&t.options.onceOnly&&1==t.firedElems.length&&(e=[e[0]]);for(var n,r=0;n=e[r];r++)n&&n.callback&&n.callback.call(n.elem,n.elem);t&&t.options.onceOnly&&1==t.firedElems.length&&t.me.unbindEventWithSelectorAndCallback.call(t.target,t.selector,t.callback)},checkChildNodesRecursively:function(e,t,n,r){for(var i,o=0;i=e[o];o++)n(i,t,r)&&r.push({callback:t.callback,elem:i}),i.childNodes.length>0&&l.checkChildNodesRecursively(i.childNodes,t,n,r)},mergeArrays:function(e,t){var n,r={};for(n in e)e.hasOwnProperty(n)&&(r[n]=e[n]);for(n in t)t.hasOwnProperty(n)&&(r[n]=t[n]);return r},toElementsArray:function(t){return n===t||"number"==typeof t.length&&t!==e||(t=[t]),t}}}(),c=function(){var e=function(){this._eventsBucket=[],this._beforeAdding=null,this._beforeRemoving=null};return e.prototype.addEvent=function(e,t,n,r){var i={target:e,selector:t,options:n,callback:r,firedElems:[]};return this._beforeAdding&&this._beforeAdding(i),this._eventsBucket.push(i),i},e.prototype.removeEvent=function(e){for(var t,n=this._eventsBucket.length-1;t=this._eventsBucket[n];n--)if(e(t)){this._beforeRemoving&&this._beforeRemoving(t);var r=this._eventsBucket.splice(n,1);r&&r.length&&(r[0].callback=null)}},e.prototype.beforeAdding=function(e){this._beforeAdding=e},e.prototype.beforeRemoving=function(e){this._beforeRemoving=e},e}(),a=function(t,r){var i=new c,o=this,a={fireOnAttributesModification:!1};return i.beforeAdding(function(n){var i,l=n.target;(l===e.document||l===e)&&(l=document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0]),i=new MutationObserver(function(e){r.call(this,e,n)});var c=t(n.options);i.observe(l,c),n.observer=i,n.me=o}),i.beforeRemoving(function(e){e.observer.disconnect()}),this.bindEvent=function(e,t,n){t=l.mergeArrays(a,t);for(var r=l.toElementsArray(this),o=0;o<r.length;o++)i.addEvent(r[o],e,t,n)},this.unbindEvent=function(){var e=l.toElementsArray(this);i.removeEvent(function(t){for(var r=0;r<e.length;r++)if(this===n||t.target===e[r])return!0;return!1})},this.unbindEventWithSelectorOrCallback=function(e){var t,r=l.toElementsArray(this),o=e;t="function"==typeof e?function(e){for(var t=0;t<r.length;t++)if((this===n||e.target===r[t])&&e.callback===o)return!0;return!1}:function(t){for(var i=0;i<r.length;i++)if((this===n||t.target===r[i])&&t.selector===e)return!0;return!1},i.removeEvent(t)},this.unbindEventWithSelectorAndCallback=function(e,t){var r=l.toElementsArray(this);i.removeEvent(function(i){for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)if((this===n||i.target===r[o])&&i.selector===e&&i.callback===t)return!0;return!1})},this},s=function(){function e(e){var t={attributes:!1,childList:!0,subtree:!0};return e.fireOnAttributesModification&&(t.attributes=!0),t}function t(e,t){e.forEach(function(e){var n=e.addedNodes,i=e.target,o=[];null!==n&&n.length>0?l.checkChildNodesRecursively(n,t,r,o):"attributes"===e.type&&r(i,t,o)&&o.push({callback:t.callback,elem:i}),l.callCallbacks(o,t)})}function r(e,t){return l.matchesSelector(e,t.selector)&&(e._id===n&&(e._id=o++),-1==t.firedElems.indexOf(e._id))?(t.firedElems.push(e._id),!0):!1}var i={fireOnAttributesModification:!1,onceOnly:!1,existing:!1};f=new a(e,t);var c=f.bindEvent;return f.bindEvent=function(e,t,r){n===r?(r=t,t=i):t=l.mergeArrays(i,t);var o=l.toElementsArray(this);if(t.existing){for(var a=[],s=0;s<o.length;s++)for(var u=o[s].querySelectorAll(e),f=0;f<u.length;f++)a.push({callback:r,elem:u[f]});if(t.onceOnly&&a.length)return r.call(a[0].elem,a[0].elem);setTimeout(l.callCallbacks,1,a)}c.call(this,e,t,r)},f},u=function(){function e(){var e={childList:!0,subtree:!0};return e}function t(e,t){e.forEach(function(e){var n=e.removedNodes,i=[];null!==n&&n.length>0&&l.checkChildNodesRecursively(n,t,r,i),l.callCallbacks(i,t)})}function r(e,t){return l.matchesSelector(e,t.selector)}var i={};d=new a(e,t);var o=d.bindEvent;return d.bindEvent=function(e,t,r){n===r?(r=t,t=i):t=l.mergeArrays(i,t),o.call(this,e,t,r)},d},f=new s,d=new u;t&&i(t.fn),i(HTMLElement.prototype),i(NodeList.prototype),i(HTMLCollection.prototype),i(HTMLDocument.prototype),i(Window.prototype);var h={};return r(f,h,"unbindAllArrive"),r(d,h,"unbindAllLeave"),h}}(window,"undefined"==typeof jQuery?null:jQuery,void 0);
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var nameElement;
function showText(textToShow, elementToEdit){
jQuery(elementToEdit).text(textToShow);
}

function hideElement(elementToHide) {
jQuery(elementToHide).css({"visibility" : "hidden", "position" : "absolute"});
}

function showElement(elementToShow) {
jQuery(elementToShow).css({"visibility" : "", "position" : ""});
}

jQuery(document).arrive("#input_field", function() { 
nameElement = jQuery('#input_field').parent().parent().parent().parent().find(".setting-name");
    showText("input_field", nameElement ); 
showElement(nameElement.parent().parent())
});

jQuery(document).leave("#input_field", function() { 
    showText("", nameElement); 
hideElement(nameElement.parent().parent());
});
</script>
"""
return FullHTML
```

Comment: Can you share some more implementation details? Maybe some screenshots? Does this hide the input on the build page, _before_ building, based on previous selections? (Like a reactive reference param?)

Comment: @DenhamCoote I added second solution and slightly better description.

Comment: Sorry I can't be of more help - I'm tinkering with something along the same lines but didn't get as far as you.  Another option, depending on your preferences, might be not to bother to hide the fields, but rather disable them. Might be easier / less error prone.

Comment: @DenhamCoote I added one more functionality. Thanks to that it works fully as I intended.

Comment: @StKob please can you tell where i need to add the JS script and call FullHTML in groovy script